# in C++, Will the compiler always copy the whole block of an inline function to where it gets called?

Tags: c++

*As far as I know:

- The original intent of inline (perhaps come from C? ) is meant to
  copy the whole block of code of the inline function to where we call it
  directly without needing to go and execute it separately and then
  return back from there.
- Whereas, inline in C++ rather means  "multiple definitions are
  permitted" rather than "inlining[/inline substitution/inline
  expansion] is preferred".

*Question :
In C++ when an inline function gets called, does it still always mean that: "it will always copy the whole block of copy of inline function to where it gets called" 
Or 'sometimes' will just go and execute the inline function separately like any other normal function?

Comment: is this really different from your last question?

Comment: Check out cppreference.com. `inline`, apart from what you found out about multiple definitions, is just a suggestion and up to the compiler.

Comment: "inline function" in c++ has a meaning that is seperate from whether the function is inlined at the call site. In c++ the keyword `inline` is to specify a function as "inline function" which is nowadays rather unrelated to whether the function is inlined at the call site. When the function is inlined at the call site then its the whole function, only part of the function would be pointless

Comment: Simple answer: no. Use implementation-specific directions (e.g. `always_inline`(`__attribute__((always_inline))`, or `[[gnu::always_inline]]` post-c++17) in gcc) if you want to force inlining.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai yes. somebody asked me to split the post into 2 different posts - so I did it :)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  i did read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline several times but can not fully understand and feel so unsure :)

Comment: @Crackie Have you read this paragraph? _"The original intent of the `inline` keyword was to serve as an indicator to the optimizer that inline substitution of a function is preferred over function call.... Since this meaning of the keyword `inline` is **non-binding**, compilers **are free** to use inline substitution for any function that's not marked `inline`, and **are free** to generate function calls to any function marked `inline`."_ I believe it directly answers your question.

Comment: @Crackie The last time I looked at this in detail I found that my compiler sometimes failed to inline functions I had declared inline, and did inline functions I had not declared inline. So the answer is no, with regard to really inlining functions (it's also called *open coding*) the compiler does not always respect the inline keyword or lack thereof.

Comment: @DanielLangr I didn't realize that my question is already answer; thank a lot :)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai if this is a duplicate please mark it as duplicate, or hint us with the link to a previous duplicate.

Comment: @Red.Wave sorry, not sure if this is a duplicate. I think OP was told to fix their old question then posted this one. If they do not want to fix the old question too, maybe they can delete it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76942687/what-is-the-real-purpose-of-the-compiler-making-all-non-static-member-functions.

Comment: @WeijunZhou And just for completeness, `__forceinline` for MSVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inline` keyword historically was used to *enable* but not *force* the inlining optimization. For this, the One Definition Rule was relaxed, and multiple definitions are permitted. (i.e. the distinction between C and C++ which you try to make does not exist as you describe it).

As part of the optimization phase, inlining can interact with other optimizations such as dead code removal. For instance, a null pointer check might not be necessary, because after inlining it's clear that the pointer can't be null in that particular context:

```
inline void f(int* p) { if (p) std::cout << *p; }
int a = 3;
f(&a); // p can't be nullptr
```

And while optimizing, it is also possible that the dereference of `p` is skipped entirely and the resulting assembly is just as if you wrote `std::cout << 3`.

Hence, it is quite possible that the optimizers just copies a *partial* implementation.

Because this is an optimization, the optimizer can use whatever heuristics it wants. These may include factors that vary from call to call. For example, "being inside a `for-loop`" is a heuristic that favors inlining. Having to inline a large block of code favors not inlining (but see the previous observation).

Hence, it is quite possible that the optimizers make different inlining decisions per call site.